# SSRS Column chart fixed width

Tags: reporting-services

Is to possible to achieve the fixed column width in SSRS column chart.
Currently the column width changes based on no of records.
Could you please help?

Comment: The column width changes based on the number of rows returned, or the number of values returned in each row?

Comment: yes that is correct. based on number of rows returned it changes.